# Lazy loading of image in tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Im trying to load the image of my uitableviewcells in lazy mode.

I'm trying to do it in the simplest possible way, I saw a lot of examples but they were going further than my purpose.

This is what Im doing currently, and its not working:

```
// Configure the cell...
    Info *info = [self.Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = info.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = info.platform;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    //The image is downloaded in asynchronous 

    NSBlockOperation *downloadingImgBlock = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        NSString* imageURL = info.imgURL;
        NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    }];
[self.queue addOperation:downloadingImgBlock];
```

Why it's not working? And how could it work?

Comment: Did you try to set the image on the main thread, call dispatch_async and pass the main thread

Comment: have you tried the Grand Dispatch yet?

Comment: No to both questions, could you tell me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do it setting the image with:

```
– performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:
```

After the image is downloaded

Answer (score 5):

Man, [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/) is your friend! Just set the image url and everything is handled for you, downloading, caching. It's awesome.

Comment: I cannot use libraries, it has to be done in my code in the simplest way, but thanks

Comment: I cannot use 3rd part component

Answer (score 1):

Try the following codes

```
  ......
  __block UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  __block UIImage *img;
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: imageURL]]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

            cell.imageView.image = img;

            }
        });


    });
  ......
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the 3rd party library source code would be easiest, but here's how you would do it in code.  You are going to want to make a `NSMutableArray` either as a property in your `.h` or at the top of your `.m` like this:

```
@implementation viewController{
     NSMutableArray *picList;
}
```

and in `-initWithCoder:` or, whatever init you are overloading:

```
picList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

in `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` (fullPicURL is the URL):

```
if([self imageExists:fullPicURL]){

    shoePic = [picList objectForKey:fullSmallPicURL];   

} else {

    NSURL *picURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullPicURL];

    shoePic = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:picURL]];
    NSDictionary *thisImage = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:shoePic forKey:fullSmallPicURL];
    [cachedImages addEntriesFromDictionary:thisImage];
}
```

where `-imageExists:` is a function you write which checks the dictionary for the url. The object is the picture itself, the key is the url. Then you do `cell.image = showPic;`, or whatever you want to call it, and you're done for cacheing. In order to load them asynchronously, do this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:shoes];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedShoeData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];

});
```

and at the end of fetchedData:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

then just make sure you edit `–numberOfSectionsInTableView:` to change itself if it has to.  Might be some other things you need to do to get it working 100%, let me know

Answer (score 0):

try this one, I'm using always this scheme **to load images asynchronously:**

*(I haven't found simplest way.)*

```
- (void)inAnyMethod {

    // ...

    void (^blockLoadPhoto)() =  ^{
        UIImage *_imageTemporary = [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."];
        if (_imageTemporary) {
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setPhoto:) withObject:_imageTemporary waitUntilDone:true];
        }
    };

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), blockLoadPhoto);

    // ...

}

- (void)setPhoto:(UIImage *)photo {
    // do something with the loaded image
}
```