# Alternative to NSData in image loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, cocoa-touch, nsdata

I currently have a RSS feed loading into a Navigation Controller, but I just recently added images onto the cells, I am using NSData to store the image data, but it is ***very laggy*** so this means I need a better way to store that data.

This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];
    NSString *textFiltered = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"description"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [textFiltered stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"pubDate"];
    //NSString *imageURLString = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"enclosure"];

    NSURL *url = feeds[indexPath.row][@"url"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


    return cell;
}
```

Any good alternatives and if so how do I use it correctly?

Comment: offload your image loading in a secondary thread. There is a very good WWDC talk about that from Andy. See here. http://andymatuschak.org/talks.html

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11523408/760275

Comment: @Julien, Apple does NOT recommend creating a new thread. The system has built-in support for async downloading with NSURLConnection and the new-in-iOS7 NSURLSession. Threads are expensive to create and tie up physical memory. Ramesh's answer, below, is the better way to go.

Comment: @DuncanC: I did not recommend creating a new thread but defer loading in a secondary thread. Including UIImage creation. Whatever Apple recommends is (obviously) in Andy's session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlUTF8];

    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         UIImage *imagemain=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
         //         CGSize size=imagemain.size;
  //compulsary you have to give resize the image.....
         UIImage *compimage=[self  resizeImage:imagemain resizeSize:CGSizeMake(45,45)];
         Cell.imgProfile.image=compimage;
         //         CGSize size1=compimage.size;
     }];
 this is perfect code for image loading in tableview cell.......

for Resizing Method

-(UIImage *) resizeImage:(UIImage *)orginalImage resizeSize:(CGSize)size
 {
CGFloat actualHeight = orginalImage.size.height;
CGFloat actualWidth = orginalImage.size.width;
//  if(actualWidth <= size.width && actualHeight<=size.height)
//  {
//      return orginalImage;
//  }
float oldRatio = actualWidth/actualHeight;
float newRatio = size.width/size.height;
if(oldRatio < newRatio)
{
    oldRatio = size.height/actualHeight;
    actualWidth = oldRatio * actualWidth;
    actualHeight = size.height;
}
else
{
    oldRatio = size.width/actualWidth;
    actualHeight = oldRatio * actualHeight;
    actualWidth = size.width;
}

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0,0.0,actualWidth,actualHeight);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
[orginalImage drawInRect:rect];
orginalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return orginalImage;
```

}

Comment: I can clarify this works. I just had to get rid of `compimage` and change up a few variable names.

Answer (score 1):

`NSData` is not slow, it is the loading from the url, assuming that the url is an Internet load.

The problem is you are loading the image on the main thread. You should load it async and then update the cell when the image loads.

You can use:

```
+ (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler
```

In the `completionHandler` convert to an `UIImage` and notify the table to reload with the image.

Additionally, if applicable cache the image in a local file.